# Retrieving data from the database using cursor.

Tags: android, sqlite, hashmap

I was trying to read data from the database using **HashMap** but every time i run the program in emulator it got struck. I tried using Arraylist with **BasicNameValuePair* to retrieve data but this also didn't worked out.
Here is the code where i read data.

```
DatabaseHandler databaseHandler = new DatabaseHandler(
        getApplicationContext());
HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();
user = databaseHandler.userDetails();

email = user.get("email").toString();
password = user.get("password").toString();
```

and here is my userDetails() method

```
   public HashMap<String, String> userDetails() {

        HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM login";
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        // move to first row
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            user.put("email", cursor.getString(1));
            user.put("password", cursor.getString(2));
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return user;

    }
```

logcat is showing error

```
07-16 17:13:23.272: E/AndroidRuntime(1396):     at com.ved_main.mainpage.VerifyMainActivity.onCreate(VerifyMainActivity.java:56)
07-16 17:54:10.332: E/AndroidRuntime(1501): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-16 17:54:10.332: E/AndroidRuntime(1501): Process: com.ved_main.mainpage, PID: 1501
07-16 17:54:10.332: E/AndroidRuntime(1501): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ved_main.mainpage/com.ved_main.mainpage.VerifyMainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-16 17:54:10.332: E/AndroidRuntime(1501):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
07-16 17:54:10.332: E/AndroidRuntime(1501):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
07-16 17:54:10.332: E/AndroidRuntime(1501):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
07-16 17:54:10.332: E/AndroidRuntime(1501):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
07-16 17:54:10.332: E/AndroidRuntime(1501):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-16 17:54:10.332: E/AndroidRuntime(1501):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-16 17:54:10.332: E/AndroidRuntime(1501):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
07-16 17:54:10.332: E/AndroidRuntime(1501):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-16 17:54:10.332: E/AndroidRuntime(1501):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-16 17:54:10.332: E/AndroidRuntime(1501):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
07-16 17:54:10.332: E/AndroidRuntime(1501):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
07-16 17:54:10.332: E/AndroidRuntime(1501):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-16 17:54:10.332: E/AndroidRuntime(1501): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-16 17:54:10.332: E/AndroidRuntime(1501):     at com.ved_main.mainpage.VerifyMainActivity.onCreate(VerifyMainActivity.java:54)
07-16 17:54:10.332: E/AndroidRuntime(1501):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
07-16 17:54:10.332: E/AndroidRuntime(1501):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
07-16 17:54:10.332: E/AndroidRuntime(1501):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
07-16 17:54:10.332: E/AndroidRuntime(1501):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: `VerifyMainActivity.java:54` please send the code block that consists 54th line of the mentioned activity.

Comment: 54th line is the same `email = user.get("email").toString();` that i have written above

Comment: You have to check if user is not empty before getting the "email" value from it.

Comment: `databaseHandler.userDetails()` I guess this method returns null where you assign the return value to HashMap user. If you send that method too we might be able to pinpoint the exact cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table does not have any rows, so there is no `email` entry in the `user` object.